# Is it correct to write "the adjacent room" even if there are multiple adjacent rooms?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, articles

Recently, I posted [a puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98577/there-are-2-001-doors-leading-to-2-001-hallways-how-quickly-can-you-find-the-wa) on Puzzling.SE.

The puzzle describes a prison containing thousands of hallways which all run next to each other, like the pipes in a pan flute. In my description of the prison, I wrote that most of the hallways have a door which leads to **the adjacent** hallway.

Someone wrote in the comments that my use of the word "the" is incorrect. After all, most of the hallways have *two* adjacent hallways, and so I can't write "**the** adjacent hallway"; I have to write "**an** adjacent hallway" or "**one of the** adjacent hallways".

However, I could swear that it's reasonably common in English to write things like "the adjacent room" and "the adjacent lot" even when there are multiple adjacent rooms and multiple adjacent lots, and no way for the reader to determine exactly which room or lot was meant.

I could very easily imagine someone saying "I was lecturing once when I heard a strange noise from **the** adjacent classroom", even when there are two adjacent classrooms; and "there are trees on the line between this lot and **the** adjacent lot", even when there are several adjacent lots. To me, if you replace "the" with "an" in either of those examples, it sounds  bit like you're trying to draw the reader's attention to the existence of a new classroom or lot that they weren't aware of before.

Is my thinking correct? Is it really appropriate to write "the adjacent room" when there are several adjacent rooms, or am I just imagining things?

I'm interested primarily in whether or not "the" is actually used this way by careful writers, not in what textbooks for English students have to say about the matter.

Comment: Don't you think "reasonably common" mistakes are no justifcation for getting things wrong?

If you want to be correct then no, you may not use "the adjacent hallway". You do need "an adjacent hallway" or "one of the adjacent hallways"…

If you don't mind being seen as incorrect… or… uh… "wrong", use what words you wish…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Of course I think that reasonably common mistakes are no justification for getting things wrong. I'm not asking if it's a reasonably common mistake; I'm asking if it's the way careful writers habitually write.

Comment: Then why not do the research? Why not use any of the tools available through any search engine to show how all writers habitually write, then make your own conclusion about what  careful writers do differently?

Alternatively, why not drop the Question as broadly unanswerable?

Comment: In any case, I've edited the question to make it more similar to other well-received [grammaticality] questions. I'm now simply asking "is this correct?" instead of explicitly asking what careful writers do.

Comment: Sorry, although of course rules have exceptions, this ins't one of them.

it's reasonably common in English to say "the adjacent (noun)" even when there are multiple adjacent (nouns) and no way for the reader to determine which is meant.

Hopefully it's vastly less common to write that… the difference being that unless we're lazy, we give much more thought to what we write.

Even it was an every-day mistake, it would still always and without exception be a mistake.

If too few people care, it will become acceptable but happily, that hasn't yet happened.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "Although of course rules have exceptions, this ins't one of them" – And if you have a source for that assertion, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: @TannerSwett **The** would be quite acceptable in the right context. For instance, *the adjacent hallway that's painted green*, where only one of the several adjacent hallways is painted green. So long as there is some kind of context whereby **the** is can be seen to reference a specific adjacent hallway, then there's no problem with the definite article.

Comment: @TannerSwett However, I see no problem with the use of **the** in the first place—because you haven't described a situation where a hallway has more than one door. To quote you: "*I wrote that most of the hallways have **a door** which leads to the adjacent hallway."* If that's accurate, then the criticism is based on a false premise. If you say **a door** that means **one door**, and if there's only one of them, then there can only be one adjacent hallway, meaning that **the** is still fine. The problem is that they misconstrued your description. You never mention two adjacent hallways.

Comment: @TannerSwett (Unless, of course, the description of the puzzle in this question is wrong, and you actually described a situation in which *most of the hallways have **doors** which lead to adjacent **hallways**.*)

Comment: @JasonBassford "If you say a door that means one door, and if there's only one of them, then there can only be one adjacent hallway" – Are you saying that hallways are only adjacent if there's a door connecting them?

Comment: @TannerSwett Perhaps not technically, but practically. If you're saying to use a door to get to an adjacent hallway, but there **is** no door on one side of the hallway you're on, it's only logical to assume that only a single adjacent hallway (the only one with a door leading to it) can be the one that's referenced. That being so, **the** is acceptable within that context.

Comment: @Tanner Swett Sorry, it doesn't work that way…

Like them or not, rules are rules. That much, we all know.

When you want to make an exception, make it… don't pretend it's up to anyone else not to make it.

If you want to debate that, why not go to Discussions?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Where are you getting all this information from? I assume you're not just making it up, so you must have a source.

Comment: @Tanner Swett Of course I have sources and rather obviously those are the meanings of English and the workings of logic.

If either of those is difficult for you please either explain your difficulty, or go to Discussions… preferably, both.

Comment: 'By careful writers' and 'in logic classes' don't always boil down to the same thing. English interpretation is often governed by pragmatics (what 95+% of competent native speakers would understand by a statement etc). If you're going into more precisionist interpretations, it's only fair to clarify which rules you've chosen to use. So on ELU, this must be 'answer arbitrary / dependent on specific language usages needing spelling out by the inquisitor / opinion-based'.

Answer (score 1):

One matter hasn't been addressed so far: the text the OP discusses is *a puzzle*. If you're listening to someone telling a story, and they said "I was lecturing once when I heard a strange noise from the adjacent classroom" (an example by the OP), then you might not trouble to ask them to clarify whether it was the one on the left, the right, or wherever. You might take it for granted that this detail doesn't matter to your appreciation of their story.

By contrast, a puzzle is different. The setter (the person posing the puzzle) needs to make it clear what information the solver is told, and what they are not told. Are the hallways connected in pairs but the pairs separate? Or is each hallway connected to both its neighbours? Or perhaps the setter specifically intends not to tell the solver. The solver can't glean this from context, because the puzzle statement is the entire context. In such a situation, accuracy of wording is critical.

Answer (score 0):

I've found several uses of the phrase "the adjacent room", in cases where there are multiple adjacent rooms and no way of identifying a particular one, in printed books from mainstream publishers.

Given these citations, I can only conclude that this usage is perfectly grammatical and correct.

All of these are from Google Books.

Jones, Thomas J. A. Professional Management of Housekeeping Operations. United Kingdom, Wiley, 2007, p. 216:

> [...] engineer with a bolt cutter in preparation for cutting the chain on the door.
>
> There are two specific exceptions to the concerns stated, both of which should be considered before using the emergency master key or the bolt cutter. The room may have been sold as part of a suite that adjoins **the adjacent room**.

Ermann, Michael. Architectural Acoustics Illustrated. United States, Wiley, 2015, p. 179:

> Design rooms that are not noise sensitive as buffer zones between noisy spaces and quiet spaces. For instance, place a row of closets, utility rooms, vestibules, and bicycle storage rooms between residential units. Experience suggests that **the room two-doors-down** is much quieter than **the adjacent room**, so insert buffer rooms to effectively move noisy rooms “two doors down.”

Jellison, Judith. Including Everyone: Creating Music Classrooms Where All Children Learn. United States, Oxford University Press, 2015 (no page number):

> We've also experienced times when we cannot concentrate on a task because of distracting sounds from others in the same room, from a malfunctioning heating or cooling system, or from musicians practicing in **the adjacent room**.

Comment: *"Given these citations, I can only conclude that this usage is perfectly grammatical."* - But grammatical and semantically correct are not the same thing. It's possible to be grammatically correct but completely nonsensical. (Not that the examples you found are nonsensical, but "grammatical" is not the bar you need to clear here.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Yep, I suppose that's true. I changed it to say "grammatical and correct".

Comment: In each of the quotes, the context seems to imply a specific adjacent room.